# org.jboss.resteasy.core.NoMessageBodyWriterFoundFailure: Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type: of media type: application/xml

Tags: java, resteasy

```
@POST
@Path("/getmethod")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
Response getMethod(SomeVO someVO);
```

In my ***.ear I can see resteasy-jaxb-provider-2.2.0.GA.jar & resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar both present but while trying to access this method, I am facing this error :

> [org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher]
>   (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Failed executing POST
>   //getmethod:
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.NoMessageBodyWriterFoundFailure: Could not
>   find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type: *VO of media
>   type: application/xml     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponse.writeTo(ServerResponse.java:216)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.3.Final-redhat-1]    at

org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeJaxrsResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:585)

> [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.3.Final-redhat-1]    at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:506)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.3.Final-redhat-1]    at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:119)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.3.Final-redhat-1]    at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.3.Final-redhat-1]    at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.3.Final-redhat-1]    at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.3.Final-redhat-1]    at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
>   [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.1.Final-redhat-1]
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:]     at
>   org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
>   [jboss-as-web-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:679)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:931)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown
>   Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was not adding the annotation at the VO class attributes.

Sample:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "user")
public class TestVo {

    String order;
    String serial;
    int number;

    @XmlElement
    public String getorder() {
        return order;
    }

    public void setorder(String order) {
        this.order = order;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getserial() {
        return serial;
    }

    public void setserial(String serial) {
        this.serial = serial;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public int getnumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setnumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve it by refering below link.. He suggested to add 
        
        org.jboss.resteasy
        resteasy-jaxb-provider
        2.2.0.GA
    
jar

http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/resteasy-could-not-find-messagebodywriter-for-response-object-of-typexx-of-media-type-applicationxml/